# Not returning error when username or email exists

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure ouit why its not reporting a validation error when there is a match in my database for my username or email address.

It still shows this as the post parameters which are right. It does do two different post requests upon taking the focus off either.

Register Controller:

```
public function is_username_available()
{
    if ($this->users_model->is_username_available($this->input->post('username')))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }        
}

public function is_email_available()
{
    if ($this->users_model->is_email_available($this->input->post('email_address')))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }        
}
```

register.js

```
rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 12,
            remote: {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'register/is_username_available',
                data: {
                    'username': function() { return $('#username').val(); }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        },
        email_address: {
            email: true,
            remote: {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'register/is_email_available',
                data: {
                    'email_address': function() { return $("#email_address").val(); }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        }
```

Users_Model:

```
/**
 * Check if username available for registering
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  bool
 */
function is_username_available($username)
{
    $this->db->select('username', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('LOWER(username)=', strtolower($username));

    $query = $this->db->get($this->users_table);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->num_rows() == 0;
}

/**
 * Check if email available for registering
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  bool
 */
function is_email_available($email)
{
    $this->db->select('email', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('LOWER(email)=', strtolower($email));

    $query = $this->db->get($this->users_table);
    return $query->num_rows() == 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `callback`?

Comment: I do have one but I'm also trying to do one with client side as a double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ajax not accept TRUE or FALSE on the server side, you should send a string that tells ajax you have to do. For example:

in model:

```
function is_username_available($username)
{
    $this->db->select('username', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('LOWER(username)=', strtolower($username));

    $query = $this->db->get($this->users_table);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      // no available
      return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
      // available
      return TRUE;
    }
}
```

in controller:

```
public function is_username_available()
{
    if (!$this->users_model->is_username_available($this->input->post('username')))
    {
        // no available
        exit('n');
    }
    else
    {
        // available
        exit('y');
    }        
}
```

Find an Event "success" in your library jquery, and asks something like:

```
success: function(data){ 

      if(data == 'y')
      {
        alert('available');
      }
      else
      {
        alert('no available');
      }
}
```

I think the rules of the validation plugin work one by one. Then you can send multiple answers depending on which is the first consultation, for example, first user message: exit ('user_y') exit ('user_n') and email: exit ('email_y') exit ('email_n' )

and at the "success" of the plugin you are using a switch as follows:

```
success: function(data){ 

      switch(data)
      {
        case 'user_y':
              alert('user_msg_yes');
        break;
        case 'user_n':
              alert('user_msg_no');
        break;
        case 'email_y':
              alert('email_msg_yes');
        break;
        case 'email_n':
              alert('email_msg_no');
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: This is great however how do I incorporate the messages into the sucesss. messages: {
            username: {
                remote: 'The username is already in use'
            },
            email_address: {
                remote: 'There is already an account set up that uses that email address!'
            }
        }, 

Or should I make the php in the controller return an array  with a yes no and a message.